# Error compiling .Rnw in TeXstudio (knitr with PdfLaTeX)

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texstudio, knitr

I´ve been trying to get the minimal Demofile for knitr running and compiling in TeXstudio, but I keep getting errormessages.

Here´s the info, mybe somebody can help me out about what I´m doing wrong:

I´m compiling this example file from the knitr website:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Here is a code chunk.

<<foo, fig.height=4>>=
1+1
letters
chartr('xie', 'XIE', c('xie yihui', 'Yihui Xie'))
par(mar=c(4, 4, .2, .2)); plot(rnorm(100))
@

You can also write inline expressions, e.g. $\pi=\Sexpr{pi}$, and \Sexpr{1.598673e8} is a big number.

\end{document}
```

I have this added in my Builds as a user command in TeXstudio:

```
knitr:knitr   "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/bin/Rscript.exe" -e "library(knitr, lib.loc='C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.0'); knit2pdf('%.Rnw')"
```

(based on the info here http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/editors/#comment-784855735 and here http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/editors/ )

Now when compiling I get the error

```
Couldn´t start Build & View:PdfLaTeX:"C:Program Files (x86)/MikTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 - interaction=nonstopmode "002-minimal".tex .
```

and when I hit Ok, it says:

```
Logfile not found!
```

TeXstudio works fine with simple .tex-documents.
So what am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: first, you have to put R in the `PATH` of your OS

Comment: Hey Yihui,
first thanks for the great package, helps a lot!
Secondly: thanks, it worked! Was really happy about it. Interestingly enough there was a little tweak to it:

Under Windows 7 you can change the PATH variable by clicking Start -> right click Computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables, lower window.

But when I put it there, it didn´t work, although it was correctly set. (My path to R is "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\x64")

But the lower solution here:[link](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Rcmd-is-not-found-in-my-PATH_0021) by cmd helped. Thx!

Comment: Jsut a short addition:
After getting it to work, I checked the PATH under Start -> right click computer... again, and although TeXstudio was now compiling Rnw, the PATH variable hadn´t changed (so no path to R included).

I guess it was put somewhere else...
Still works. Thanks again.

Comment: @Can, +1 for this question, can u please explicitly describe your workflow in windows7 platform with MWE in more details. It didn't work, as you can only set *one* Path at a time and was already set to `C:\texlive\2013\bin\win32`, how to set it to `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\i386` instead?. Doest this work for XeLaTex instead of PdfLaTex?

Comment: @ doctorate: Hi! Firstly I guess you´re in the wrong (upper) window when searchin for the path-variable (`Start -> right click Computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables`, lower window). Secondly the other solution was: Create a txtfile, that contains just this: `set PATH=C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\x64;%PATH%` where you change `C:\...\x64` with the corresponding directory of your R install. Rename the txtfile to  `setpath.bat`, then open commandline, switch to the directory (where setpath.bat is) in cmd and then put in `CMD /K setpath.bat` and hit enter. Should do the job.

Comment: I had the same problem with TeXstudio and tried everything without success. Then I realized the problem was between the chair and the keyboard as I was trying to build it with `[F1] Build&View` which runs just the usual LaTeX compiler and you get the same error as above.

Solution is to run the knitr user created command. In default by `[ALT] + [SHIFT] + [F1]`.

Comment: How do you embed/mix this code  from a rnw file with other code on a differnt tex file?

Comment: @skan: You should be fine using `\input{filepath}`.

Comment: These settings don't work for me. When I compile the document with the user defined option It doesn't work for me. When it finds a " \Sexpr" it says "missing $ inserted. opts_ , and some undefined control sequence errors. And it doesn't accept comments with "#". How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As can be seen in comments the solution was to add the R program folder to the system path, which corresponds to environment variable `%PATH%`.

Answer (score 0):

install `tinytex` in RStudio using  `tinytex::install_tinytex()`

```
tools-->global option--->Sweave
check : knitr
check : pdfLaTeX
check : Use tinytex when compiling.tex files
```

If not work, then uninstall ur miktex in ur computer and it' will work
After that reinstall miktex...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!